# MTD StyledStringElement has a white background after IOS 7.0 upgrade

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I've recently upgraded my app to IOS 7. On one on my screens I'm using MTD StyledStringElement. The elements background is white on IOS 7, and I can't figure out how to change it back to clear. I've tried to set the background color to clear but it's not working for me. If I set the table view to null then the my background does not appear at all.

Thanks in advance.

```
        tableView.SeparatorColor = UIColor.Clear;
        var cell = base.GetCell(tableView);
        cell.BackgroundView = null;

        tableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        cell.BackgroundColor = null;
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = null;

        cell.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all the code above dealing with background colors is not necessary.

Just set the `BackgroundColor` of your `StyledStringElement` instance to `UIColor.Clear`.

See for reference the [MT.Dialog source on Github](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L770)